# MySQLdump define the path

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to backup a MySQL database:

```
$ mysqldump -u ruby -p idm_production > /home/username/idm_backup_2010_10_23.sql
```

Enter password: 
mysqldump: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show fields from `arguments`': Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_721_0.MYI' (Errcode: 13) (1)

However I don't seem to have permission to write the the /tmp
Is there a way I can define the path to output the backup?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is write,

If you dont have permission try

1 - with sudo

make your user sudo

sudo -su

mysqldump -u ruby -p idm_production > /home/username/idm_backup_2010_10_23.sql

or else change the path

in this line you have already defined the path
home/username/

so an example output would be

mysqldump -u ruby -p idm_production > /backup.sql

cheers

sameera